# Best way to handle Windows dependencies when compiling with clang?

Tags: c++, c, windows, build, clang

I have a project which is just `C99` code built from a powershell build script. I call clang.exe and pass the compiler flags and input files manually.

I would like to know what is the best and simplest way to handle Windows specific dependencies such as `user32.lib` and `kernel32.lib`. For now I just put them all in a folder that I include in the project to make sure that they are present and the build succeeds. The problem with that approach is that they are big files and I would prefer to point the compiler to the libraries already on the system.

I don't want to require the user to have visual studio installed, but of course they need to have the windows sdk installed.

Comment: For anything larger than a toy project, you'll eventually want to use a build system or the mess will be hard to oversee. If it's not visual studio you could look into cmake for instance. Or maybe msbuild but if you don't know that it could be pretty hard to setup without using visual studio. All in all, recent cland/cmake support in visual studio is pretty ok so it might be the option with the least friction after all. Why do you not want it?

Comment: Because it's just a toy project and it will remain that way. It's meant to be ultra bare-bones.

Comment: In that case: use the standard way of doing this i.e. tell clang where the libraries are using the `-L` flag?